# Запустить генерацию большого файла из веб-интерфейса

Tags: php, производительность

Есть кнопка, называется "Скачать отчет".

Нажимаем на кнопку - идет запрос на сервер, на сервере генерируется файл, отдается человеку, запускается скачивание. Все хорошо

Такая же ситуация, только файлик генерится 6 минут. Сервер возвращает 504. Как быть?

Comment: Переносить генерацию отчёта в отдельный демон

Comment: @andreymal. Поделитесь, пожалуйста, примерными реализациями или может быть ссылочки есть?

Comment: К сожалению, не в курсе, как это по-хорошему делается в php (потому и не пишу ответ)

Comment: Возможно самый простой вариант -- написать отдельный php-скрипт генерации файла и вызывать его по крону (cron), настроив расписание в панели управления хостингом (если хостинг виртуальный, например). Тогда сценарий такой: 1) нажимаем на кнопку на сайте, на сервере создаётся задание на создание файла (запись в бд), и сразу возвращаем номер задания, 2) через некоторое время cron-скрипт подхватывает это задание и начинает генерить файл, когда всё готово скрипт сохраняет файл и путь к нему, 3) js с клиента ходит на сервер (раз в минуту или чаще) и проверяет не готов ли файл по номеру задания.

Answer (score 0):

Необходимо использовать javascript. Необходимо отправлять запрос переодический на сервер и проверять готов ли файл. Когда придет ответ "готов" то довать скачать.

Comment: Мало подробностей. Как сервер должен проверять, готов ли файл? Кто вообще готовит файл?

Comment: Когда человек увидит 504, js не поможет.